# Complicated precedence and order of evaluation

Tags: c

Sometimes its very hard to tell that in what order the expression will be evalauted. Is their any set of rules to know that the expression i have written will show undefined behaviour?

The expression : `printf("%d %d\n", ++n, power(2,n));` its very hard to say wheather the ++n is evaluated first or the power(2,n). This line is written in K&R. However, I see this expression absoultely fine. I'll assume that n will be incremented and used by the function call power(2,n).

Also, an expression like `A[i++] = A[j++]`. Right side of the assignment is always evaluated first and the value will be assigned to the left hand side according to what i see. But, this doesn't happen right? The nature of the expression is ambigous(totally depends on how machine pretend it).

Expression, `A[i] = i++`. According to what I see, `i` will be incremented and that value will be assigned to the left hand side?

But these above expressions doesn't work the way i think they do. What is the possible way to write the expression so i don't get any kind of unexpected result specially caring about those increment or decrement operators.

Comment: The rule of thumb is to not use sub-expressions with a side effect (for example, `++`) on a variable that is used elsewhere in the same expression.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ohhhh so that's the trick i got it

Comment: Since this is a C question [Why are these constructs undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/949433/1708801) is probably more relevant.